# Python re.sub with word

Tags: python

i have problem!

I get automatically strings (titles) with sometimes like Amazon in it. But these are most times Like that

```
..... (Amazon & Wallmart)
```

or `..... [Amazon & Wallmart]`

But i want no to delete the hole () or [] and not just the Amazon in it.

So i need to delete the complete `[Amazon & Wallmart]` or `(Amazon & Wallmart)` if Amazon is in it

I tried that, but does not work

```
name = re.sub("[\(\[].*Amazon*?[\)\]]", "", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, escape the backslashes or use the `r` prefix.

Using the former:

```
re.sub("[\\(\\[].*Amazon*?[\\)\\]]", "", name)
```

Using the latter:

```
re.sub(r"[\(\[].*Amazon*?[\)\]]", "", name)
```

In Regex, replace `.*Amazon*` with `.*Amazon.*`. The former will match anything or nothing followed by **Amazo** followed by zero or more **n***s, while the latter will match anything or nothing followed by **Amazon** followed by anything or nothing.

Also, you can use the [backreference feature](https://regular-expressions.mobi/backref.html?wlr=1) for Regex.

```
re.sub(r"([\(\[]).*Amazon.*?\1", "", name)
```